# resize height of ggplot in shinydashboard dinamically as observer

Tags: r, ggplot2, shinydashboard

I am trying to resize my ggplots but their height's value do not change using   `height = as.numeric(input$dimension[1])` in `renderPlot` as observer.

I would like to display in two fluid rows (1/2 screen's height each) 3 plots (Box2, Box3, Box4) in the third height's part of the first row, and Box5 at 100% of the height of the second fluidrow.

My body's screen should be look like this (without scrolling):

[image: My body's screen should be look like this]

```
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinydashboard)

bar <- ggplot(data=iris, aes(x=Species)) + geom_bar()

ui <- shinyUI(
  dashboardPage(
    header = dashboardHeader(),
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(),
    body = dashboardBody(
      tags$head(tags$script(
        'var dimension = [0, 0];
              $(document).on("shiny:connected", function(e) {
                  dimension[0] = window.innerWidth;
                  dimension[1] = window.innerHeight;
                  Shiny.onInputChange("dimension", dimension);
              });
              $(window).resize(function(e) {
                  dimension[0] = window.innerWidth;
                  dimension[1] = window.innerHeight;
                  Shiny.onInputChange("dimension", dimension);
              });'
      )),
      fluidRow(
        column(
          width = 6,
          fluidRow(
            box("Box1", width = 12, background = "aqua")
          )
        ),
        column(
          width = 6,
          fluidRow(
            box(width = 12, height = "auto", plotOutput("Box2", width = "auto", height = "auto"))
          ),
          fluidRow(
            box(width = 12, plotOutput("Box3", width = "auto", height = "auto"))
          ),
          fluidRow(
            box(width = 12, plotOutput("Box4", width = "auto", height = "auto"))
          )
        )
      ),
      fluidRow(
        column(
          width = 12,
          fluidRow(
            box(width = 12, plotOutput("Box5", width = "auto", height = "auto"))
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output){
  observe(
    output$Box2 <- renderPlot(
      bar,
      height = as.numeric(input$dimension[1]) *  1/ 2  * 1 / 3
    )
  )
  observe(
    output$Box3 <- renderPlot(
      bar,
      height = as.numeric(input$dimension[1]) *  1/ 2  * 1 / 3
    )
  )
  observe(
    output$Box4 <- renderPlot(
      bar,
      height = as.numeric(input$dimension[1]) *  1/ 2  * 1 / 3
    )
  )
  observe(
    output$Box5 <- renderPlot(
      bar,
      height = as.numeric(input$dimension[1]) *  1/ 2  * 1
    )
  )
})

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `height = as.numeric(input$dimension[2])`, not `input$dimension[1]`.

Instead of enclosing each `renderPlot` inside an observer, you can use `exprToFunction`:

```
output$Box2 <- renderPlot(
  bar,
  height = exprToFunction(as.numeric(input$dimension[2]) *  1/ 2  * 1 / 3)
)
```

(I think the `as.numeric` is unnecessary).

The result is better but the bottom plot still goes outside the screen. That's because of the margins of the `box` elements and the space at the top of the dashboard.

Comment: just see the same!  Thanks very much! Now I am trying to solve scrollbars because window.innerHeight is not the Height of the dashboardPage

Comment: When use `exprToFunction` instead of `observe`, get 
`Warning: Error in if: argumento tiene longitud cero
  [No stack trace available]`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the `dimension[1]` in the JS is `dimension[2]`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinydashboard)

bar <- ggplot(data=iris, aes(x=Species), ) + geom_bar()

ui <- shinyUI(
  dashboardPage(
    header = dashboardHeader(),
    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(),
    body = dashboardBody(
      tags$head(tags$script(
        'var dimension = [0, 0];
              $(document).on("shiny:connected", function(e) {
                  dimension[0] = window.innerWidth;
                  dimension[1] = window.innerHeight;
                  Shiny.onInputChange("dimension", dimension);
              });
              $(window).resize(function(e) {
                  dimension[0] = window.innerWidth;
                  dimension[1] = window.innerHeight;
                  Shiny.onInputChange("dimension", dimension);
              });'
      )),
      fluidRow(
        column(
          width = 6,
          fluidRow(
            box("Box1", width = 12, background = "aqua")
          )
        ),
        column(
          width = 6,
          fluidRow(
            box(width = 12, plotOutput("Box2", width = "auto", height = "auto"))
          ),
          fluidRow(
            box(width = 12, plotOutput("Box3", width = "auto", height = "auto"))
          ),
          fluidRow(
            box(width = 12, plotOutput("Box4", width = "auto", height = "auto"))
          )
        )
      ),
      fluidRow(
        column(
          width = 12,
          fluidRow(
            box(width = 12, plotOutput("Box5", width = "auto", height = "auto"))
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output){
  output$Box2 <- renderPlot(
    bar,
    height = exprToFunction(input$dimension[2] *  1/ 2  * 1 / 3)
  )
  output$Box3 <- renderPlot(
    bar,
    height = exprToFunction(input$dimension[2] *  1/ 2  * 1 / 3)
  )
  output$Box4 <- renderPlot(
    bar,
    height = exprToFunction(input$dimension[2] *  1/ 2  * 1 / 3)
  )
  output$Box5 <- renderPlot(
    bar,
    height = exprToFunction(input$dimension[2] *  1/ 2)
  )
})

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Although, I learn these importants details:

1. You need to get the screen from a Javascript chunk.
2. You need to observe (better use `exprToFunction`,  Thanks [Stéphane Laurent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1100107/st%C3%A9phane-laurent)) the plotOutput because the height may change.
3. because "2", you have to put ui's hegths on "auto" because you are setting up in the server.

Still aim did not set the **exact** heigth of the plots because appears unwanted vertical scrollbars in the body's dashboardPage. Grateful for someone to solve it.